# EFcore disable automatic adding properties to migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm learning to use EFCore with DDD and Clean Architecture and while it is nice to that I don't have separate data models I am currently experiencing that properties added to the models result in automatically being added to the migrations.
I know I can ignore them by using attributes, but I would like to avoid having an entity framework library being referenced in the library with the models. So I would have to explicitly remove them in the `DbContext` or `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TType>`.

But I was wondering if it is possible to disable the default behavior completely and that I have to define everything in the `DbContext` or `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TType>`so I can safely create features so I won't pollute my database and my migrations with properties that should not be stored.
I would rather have that behavior turned off and be more explicit than having magically decided for me. (Been bitten with uncontrolled behavior like that before)

Example:
Lets say I have a class Sample which is set in the DbContext in a `DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }`:

```
    public class Sample
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = new Guid();
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Now when I add the following two things they get automatically added in migrations

```
    public class Sample
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = new Guid();
        public long Value { get; set; }
        public string Remark { get; set; }

        // Assume this is lazy computed for business logic in domain and application layer
        public long LazyComputed { get { return Value * 100 ; } set { Value = Value * 100; } }
        
        // Set of foos but should not be stored in data yet due to privacy for example
        public IEnumerable<Foo> LogicFoos { get; set; } = new List<Foo>();
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = new Guid();
    }
```

Now when I add a migration it adds the Remark like I want to, but it sadly also adds the LazyComputed and a new relation with a new table Foos.
When it is a just one, or when I have a few, it is easy to manage fine. But when I have many and change several due a feature change there can be a lot of automatically adding/removing/changing, it seems easy to accidentally add fields to the migrations and repository when don't want.
Because of this I would like to be the default behavior to include to be reversed.

Comment: You will have to define the set of database properties somewhere, then write code to remove the rest. How about using a set of interfaces to define those properties? The loop to remove extra's should be fairly straightforward then...

Comment: Some related discussion on github https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14405

Comment: Entities and properties aren't added automatically, you need to explicitly create the classes and add the `DbSet<T>` properties. Those entities *are* the data model. Nothing forces you to use them as your business entities and quite often, you won't be able to use them without some kind of mapping.

Comment: Have you used the same classes as  EF and business entities perhaps? Even so, you can use the `NotMapped` attribute or `Ignore()` method in Fluent configuration to exclude  properties

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry I mean when you added a model to the DbContext in a DbSet and when you later add public properties they get added automatically, added some sample.
I just wish to prefer to be explicit in the `DbContext` and `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TType>` implementations so I don't accidently add properties that should stay out of repositories when I forget to do `Ignore()`

Comment: *"while it is nice to that I don't have separate data models"* - No, it's not nice. You are mixing domain model with data (persistence) model and want persistence layer (EF Core) to respect your rules rather than you respecting its rules. That won't happen - the short answer is no, currently EF Core does not provide control over default conventions.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't get your comment, you are saying I have to respect its rules yet you can override those rules with data annotation and code configuration to a very high degree. I can seem to even go into the model configuration, mapping and all in `OnModelCreating`.
Also it seems most examples and designs use the persistance layer / models combined with other models to reduce additional mapping as they are most times 1 to 1 with exception to additional property /method logics.

Comment: You can, but that's not recommended. Having unmapped properties is against "strongly typed query" (LINQ) - it's so easy and error prone to access these properties in LINQ to Entities query - there won't be a compile time error, but unexpected runtime exceptions or wrong behaviors. The "clean" design would use separate models and map between the two where needed  (with the help of AutoMapper or similar).